# Adding default hover buttons on Custom Formated Column

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting

I have applied custom formatting to the Name Column in the Documents library.

I do this because I want to make sure some types of files open in preview mode.

My code:

```
"$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "a",
      "txtContent": "@currentField",
      "attributes": {
        "target": "_blank",
        "class": "ms-Link sp-css-color-neutralPrimary",
        "href": "=if([$File_x0020_Type] == 'docx' || [$File_x0020_Type] == 'xlsx' || [$File_x0020_Type] == 'pptx', @currentWeb + '/_layouts/15/Doc.aspx?sourcedoc='+ [$UniqueId] + '&action=View', '')"
      },
      "style": {
        "display": "=if([$File_x0020_Type] == 'docx' || [$File_x0020_Type] == 'xlsx' || [$File_x0020_Type] == 'pptx','block', 'none')",
        "line-height": "42px",
        "font-size": "14px",
        "white-space": "nowrap",
        "text-overflow": "ellipsis",
        "overflow": "hidden"
      }
    },
    {
      "elmType": "div",
      "txtContent": "@currentField",
      "customRowAction": {
        "action": "defaultClick"
      },
      "attributes": {
        "class": "ms-Link sp-css-color-neutralPrimary"
      },
      "style": {
        "display": "=if([$File_x0020_Type] == 'docx' || [$File_x0020_Type] == 'xlsx' || [$File_x0020_Type] == 'pptx','none', 'block')",
        "line-height": "42px",
        "font-size": "14px",
        "white-space": "nowrap",
        "text-overflow": "ellipsis",
        "overflow": "hidden"
      }
    },
   {
  "elmType": "span",
  "customRowAction": {
    "action": "share"
  },
  "attributes": {
          "iconName": "Share",
          "class": "sp-field-quickActions ms-Button-flexContainer"
    },
  "style": {
  "display": "block",
  "line-height": "42px",
  "font-size": "18px",
  "white-space": "nowrap",
  "text-overflow": "ellipsis",
  "overflow": "hidden",
  "margin-left": "auto"
  },
  "customCardProps": {
  "formatter": {
    "elmType": "div",
    "txtContent": "Share the selected item with people"
  },
  "openOnEvent": "hover",
  "directionalHint": "bottomCenter",
  "isBeakVisible": true,
  "beakStyle" : {
    "backgroundColor": "white"
    }
  }
},
{
  "elmType": "span",
  "customRowAction": {
    "action": "openContextMenu"
  },
  "attributes": {
          "iconName": "MoreVertical",
          "class": "sp-field-quickActions--hover ms-Button- 
          flexContainer"
    },
  "style": {
  "display": "flex",
  "line-height": "42px",
  "font-size": "18px",
  "white-space": "nowrap",
  "text-overflow": "ellipsis",
  "overflow": "hidden",
  "height": "100%",
  "width": "40px",
  "flex-wrap": "nowrap",
  "justify-content": "center",
  "align-items": "center"
  },
  "customCardProps": {
  "formatter": {
    "elmType": "div",
    "txtContent": "Show actions"
  },
  "openOnEvent": "hover",
  "directionalHint": "bottomCenter",
  "isBeakVisible": true,
  "beakStyle" : {
    "backgroundColor": "white"
    }
  }
}
  ]
```

However, how do I add the default hover that a normal list have on files like Share and Edit?

Example:
[image]

Comment: When you add custom formatting on column, it removed default functionality. You can use share and openContextMenu actions to add those functionality back in your JSON, check: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/formatting-syntax-reference#customrowaction

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I have updated my question with two elements per your suggestion. 

Is there any way to get them to only display on a hover event?

Comment: Check if custom hover card helps you: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/formatting-syntax-reference#customcardprops and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/formatting-advanced#custom-cards-on-hover

Comment: Thanks again for answering. Sadly, that does not work to well. We have ended up with the @IsSelected property instead. 

So the users needs to select an item in order to get the share and openContextMenu.

Lets hope we get an actual onHover in the future :)

Comment: Great, glad you got it working using @isSelected. For more information & example: https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2022/08/23/sharepoint-highlight-selected-list-item-row-using-json-formatting/

Comment: I have added our conversation as an answer below. Please [accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily.

Answer (score 0):

This is a expected behavior while applying JSON formatting on SharePoint list/library column.

When you add custom JSON formatting on column, it removes all the default functionality provided by SharePoint.

For your requirements, you can use `share` and `openContextMenu` actions in `customRowAction` to add those functionality back in your JSON

**Documentation**: [JSON formatting - customRowAction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/formatting-syntax-reference#customrowaction)